# How to perform validation of TextField?

Tags: flutter, validation

Im new in flutter and I would like to perform some sort of validation of TextField. I would like to check if it is empty and if it is not whether the mail is in correct form. I'm struggling with that, I'm not sure if I should change my main class which is `StartPage` into `StatefulWidget` or not. This class contains button which redirect to new page with `TextField`. In this field we input e-mail and after clicking button some http reqest are made (after validation of course). I read that I need to change this class with `TextField` into class that `extends State`.

I found for example: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation but for me it is weird that first, we create MyApp which is `Stateless` then we redirect to class which extends `StatefulWidget` and it does not make anything then redirect to next class which `extends State`.

What is the best practice to make it? Thanks for any help.

**StartPage**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:.../ui/pages/LoginPage.dart';

class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            FlutterLogo(size: 150),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50.0,
            ),
            Text(
              'blabla',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60, color: Color(0xffffffff)),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30.0,
            ),
            Text(
              'Wypożyczaj to, czego potrzebujesz',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23, color: Color(0xffffffff)),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 70.0,
            ),
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 240, height: 60),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
                },
                child: Text('Zaloguj się',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Color(0xffffffff)),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                    Color(0xFF6FC76C),
                  ),
                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30.0,
            ),
            OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: null,
              style: ButtonStyle(
                side: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                  BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: const Text("blabla",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Color(0xffffffff),
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFE1A5BFF),
    );
  }
}
```

and Loginpage

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_signin_button/flutter_signin_button.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String baseURL =
      "....";

  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  bool emailValidate = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Zaloguj się"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            FlutterLogo(size: 130),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30.0,
            ),
            Text(
              'Zaloguj lub zarejestruj się za pomocą adresu e-mail',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Color(0xff000000),
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30.0,
            ),
            TextField(
                controller: emailController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'Adres e-mail',
                    fillColor: Color(0xffdbdbdb),
                    filled: true,
                    errorText:
                        emailValidate ? 'Please enter a Username' : null)),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 240, height: 60),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => moveToProperWindowBasedOnEmail(
                    emailController.text, context),
                child: Text('blabla',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      color: Color(0xffffffff),
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                    Color(0xFF2F45C6),
                  ),
                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 35.0,
            ),
            Text(
              'Możesz też się zalogować za pomocą:',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Color(0xff000000),
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
            SignInButton(
              Buttons.Google,
              text: "Sign up with Google",
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            SignInButton(
              Buttons.Facebook,
              text: "Sign up with Facebook",
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFEF2F7FD),
    );
  }

  Future<void> moveToProperWindowBasedOnEmail(
      String text, BuildContext context) async {
    //validation

    if (validation == 'false') {
      ....
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use the textformfield with a form widget and validator

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddUser extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddUserState createState() => _AddUserState();
}

class _AddUserState extends State<AddUser> {
  TextEditingController id = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController name = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lastName = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController age = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Graphql example',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (val) {
                      return val.isEmpty
                          ? 'please provide a valid value'
                          : null;
                    },
                    controller: id,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'ID',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (val) {
                      return val.isEmpty
                          ? 'please provide a valid value'
                          : null;
                    },
                    controller: age,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Age',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (val) {
                      return val.isEmpty
                          ? 'please provide a valid value'
                          : null;
                    },
                    controller: name,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'FirstName',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (val) {
                      return val.isEmpty
                          ? 'please provide a valid value'
                          : null;
                    },
                    controller: lastName,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'LastName',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white))),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {}
                      },
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      color: Colors.black,
                      child: Text(
                        'Submit',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                      ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I read your question, I realized that you need a basic understanding of Flutter Widget types.

that is => `Stateful` & `Stateless` widgets.

I recommend you search on these firstly. Then you will have an understanding easily. Otherwise these answers will just give you a fish, rather than teaching how to fish.

Comment: I know that for Stateless nothing can be changed on the screen and oppoiste for Stateful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use  flutter's new form widget inside that widget you can pass multiple textformfields widgets .

The best part about these new widgets is that they accept a validator key inside which you can  write all the validation for specific text field and return false in case of validation passes.

Checkout the form below for better understanding

https://github.com/mrinaljain/flutter_shoping_cart/blob/master/lib/screens/edit_product_screen.dart

Comment: the link is broken. plz fix.

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter there is two types of widgets. `Stateless` and `Stateful`.

1. Stateless widgets are those widgets whom you can't change their state. (You don't want to take action on those widgets or you don't perform any operation on those widgets). Ex:- `Text` widget.
2. Stateful widgets are those widgets whom you want to change their state. (You perform any operation on those widgets). Ex:- `ElevatedButton` widget.

[Simple Example of Form Validation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation)

You may find my answer in below link too for `TextField` validation.

[My Answer on TextField Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70559990/how-can-i-change-the-position-of-the-textformfield-validation-text-flutter/70561855#70561855)